# For[i] StringDrop Not working

Tags: bugs

I'm currently trying to code a For Loop that includes StringDrop:

`For[i=0, i<=100,i++, Print[StringDrop[list[[i,1]],4]]]`

Where list is an array and the first column (which I'm trying to extract), is called node0, node1,...

I'm getting
`Part::partd: Part specification <<1>> is longer than depth of object." and "StringDrop::strse: String or list of strings expected at position 1 in StringDrop[{{node0,node1 0.04,node8 11.11,node14 72.21},{node1,node46 1247.25,node6 20.59,node13 64.94},{node2,node66 54.18,node31 166.80,node45 1561.45},{node3,node20 133.65,node6 2.06,node11 42.43},<<3>>,{node7,node50 478.14,node9 3.15,node10 5.85},{node8,node69 577.91,node11 7.45,node12 3.18},{node9,node70 2454.28,node13 4.42,node20 16.53},<<90>>}[[0,1]],4].`

Any thoughts on why this isn't working? Thanks

EDIT:

```
    For[
 i = 0, i <= 100, i++,
 node = StringDrop[list[[i, 1]], 4] ;(*This is the node in question*)
```

Here is the list (first few entries):

```
TableForm[{{"node0", "node1 0.04", "node8 11.11", "node14 72.21"}, {
  "node1", "node46 1247.25", "node6 20.59", "node13 64.94"}, {
  "node2", "node66 54.18", "node31 166.80", "node45 1561.45"}, {
  "node3", "node20 133.65", "node6 2.06", "node11 42.43"}, {
  "node4", "node75 3706.67", "node5 0.73", "node7 1.02"}, {
  "node5", "node45 1382.97", "node7 3.33", "node11 34.54"}, {
  "node6", "node31 63.17", "node9 0.72", "node10 13.10"}]
```

Comment: "Any thoughts on why this isn't working?" is it possible to post complete self contained example to reproduce this? what is your list?

Comment: Added list - hope that helps. In hindsight, I think it might be easier if I just drop the first column of the array and add a new one with just numbers.

Comment: try changing `i = 0` to `i=1` as Mathematica index starts from 1. And try to do it without `TableForm` as that is a wrapper. And change `i <= 100` to `i <= Length@list`. Also there are better ways to do this without `For` using more functional programming.

Comment: btw, it is much to explain what is it you are actually trying to do. You just post code and error. It is better to post a small example of and input, and what is the output needed. That is all.

Comment: Does `First /@ alist` get you what you need? where `alist` is your data without the `TableForm`.

Comment: @Syed I think OP also wants to remove string from something.  Not sure from what though. That is why giving small input and expected output is always best for these types of questions.

Comment: @Nasser I agree. The OP needs to show more effort and interest.

Answer (score 2):

```
data = {{"node0", "node1 0.04", "node8 11.11", 
    "node14 72.21"}, {"node1", "node46 1247.25", "node6 20.59", 
    "node13 64.94"}, {"node2", "node66 54.18", "node31 166.80", 
    "node45 1561.45"}, {"node3", "node20 133.65", "node6 2.06", 
    "node11 42.43"}, {"node4", "node75 3706.67", "node5 0.73", 
    "node7 1.02"}, {"node5", "node45 1382.97", "node7 3.33", 
    "node11 34.54"}, {"node6", "node31 63.17", "node9 0.72", 
    "node10 13.10"}};

StringDrop[#, 4] & /@ data

(*
{{"0", "1 0.04", "8 11.11", "14 72.21"}, {"1", "46 1247.25", 
  "6 20.59", "13 64.94"}, {"2", "66 54.18", "31 166.80", 
  "45 1561.45"}, {"3", "20 133.65", "6 2.06", "11 42.43"}, {"4", 
  "75 3706.67", "5 0.73", "7 1.02"}, {"5", "45 1382.97", "7 3.33", 
  "11 34.54"}, {"6", "31 63.17", "9 0.72", "10 13.10"}}
*)
```